# Parsing XML with Identical Keys and Attribute Names

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree, zoho

I'm working with an API that outputs all its XML with the same `<FL>` key and uses the same attribute name:

```
<response uri="/webaddress/">
  <result>
    <Quotes>
      <row no="1">
        <FL val="ID">12345</FL>
        <FL val="Number">
          <![CDATA[ 12346 ]]>
        </FL>
        <FL val="Subject">
          <![CDATA[ Test ]]>
        </FL>
        <FL val="Stage">
          <![CDATA[ Draft ]]>
        </FL>
        <FL val="Valid Till">
          <![CDATA[ 2016-01-23 ]]>
        </FL>
        <FL val="CONTACTID">12121</FL>
```

I'm sure I can still work with it, but I'm pretty new and I'm struggling to find any examples that apply. I'm working in Python 3.5 with xml.etree but I don't really care what library I'm working with.

Could someone offer a example of how to get the content out of an element given a particular name-value attribute pair, i.e. store the '12345' or '12346' as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) gives some examples along with explanation.  For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for fl in root.iter('FL'):
    val = fl.attrib['val']
    text = fl.text.strip()
    print("The %s is %s" % (val, text))
```